# Windows 7 SVCHOST consumes copius RAM when searching for drivers

Tags: windows-7, memory, drivers, svchost

After much trial and error and frustration, I have discovered that svchost can consume several imperial tons of RAM if given the chance when you plug in a new piece of hardware.  I find this mind boggling and frustrating and would like some advice to know if this is normal (I don't think it is, since I've never seen it before), and maybe how to limit such behavior.  This is my second Windows 7 system.  i didn't ever notice this on the other Windows 7 system.  I've had this for about 2 years and this has been going on for a while.  Maybe a year (ish?).  I have been able to articulate the problem for a few months or so.  Today it happened twice while I was working and svchost used up so many resources it crashed my network connection somehow.  Or maybe just some other programs, I'm not sure.

I've noticed this behavior on more sophisticated devices such as cell phones and Bluetooth adapters, but not on simple USB mass storage adapters.  I've also seen this phenomenon in other instances I have not been able to track down the causes.  I have turned Superfetch off already, which may have been one of the other causes.

Windows 7 64 bit, 4GB RAM, Core i7, Dell e6530

I've tried DuckDuckGo'ing (aka Googling) and I found something almost close here on Superuser, so that gave me the idea to ask for advice here.

What can I do to further troubleshoot this issue?
What can I do to curtail this memory consumption?

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the memory usgae and share the trace: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa

Comment: You guys kill me >.< I asked the other, "duplicate", question more recently than this one.

Comment: at this time, we didn't had a solution. Now in your newer question we can answer it.

Comment: I understand what happened, I just find it kind of humorous.  It seems that Microsoft only just recently addressed this, so this question going unanswered until now was just waiting on them.

Comment: is the issue fixed? If yes, marked the answer in your newer topic.

Comment: It's better, but it's not *fixed* with the update.

Comment: Microsoft released a newer WU client. Try this one: http://superuser.com/a/997067/174557